# Dropdown button with "search" Textbox using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, drop-down-menu

I have to add a "Search Box" with a DropDown Button for searching the books.

This dropdown button should have an arrow pointing downwards and the search textbox next to it. so, wen i click on dropdown button, i should get few options (like team, personal, e........) If i select Team then the text "Search in Team" should be displayed in the textbox. A small magnifier for the searchbox will be available too.

I am using C#, XAML..its WPF app

Please help me.

Thanks

Ramm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infragistics and DevExpress have a DropDownButton control but you will have to purchase it.

I also found this [How to make a Drop Down Button in WPF](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=140)

Comment: The Link Has Expired

Answer (score 0):

In WPF every control has templates and styles.  You can look at the template for the standard WPF Dropdown and create your own template and style that will satisfy your requirements.